Why don't infinitesimals in nonstandard analysis have concrete size but infinitesimals in surreal numbers have?
I read on Wiki (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Smooth_infinitesimal_analysis#Overview) that infinitesimals in NSA don't have concrete size but infinitesimals in surreal numbers have.
How is it possible? Hyperreals and surreals both are numbers that include infinitesimals and infinite quantity.
Thanks.

Aren't surreal numbers also numbers greater than every integer ? If so, what is meant here with "concrete size" ?

@Peter, generally such claims originate with Alain Connes's campaign against NSA claiming that "the whole thing is undefinable" and depends on ultrafilters, etc.  Even though this is been refuted many times over, some echoes still persist at wiki and elsewhere.

Your Wikipedia link is about Smooth Infinitesimal Analysis, which is separate from, say, Nonstandard Analysis via Robinson's Hyperreals.

@MarkS. I assume OP is talking about the sentence "Smooth infinitesimal analysis is like nonstandard analysis in that (1) it is meant to serve as a foundation for analysis, and (2) the infinitesimal quantities do not have concrete sizes (as opposed to the surreals, in which a typical infinitesimal is $1/\omega$, where $\omega$ is a von Neumann ordinal)" which does talk about NSA.

@IzaakvanDongen Yes.

The claim that "infinitesimals in NSA don't have concrete size but infinitesimals in surreal numbers have" is a dubious one.  If anything, the opposite is true.  Thus, a recent article

Hrbacek, K.; Katz, M. "Infinitesimal analysis without the Axiom of Choice." Annals of Pure and Applied Logic 172 (2021), no. 6, 102959. https://doi.org/10.1016/j.apal.2021.102959, https://arxiv.org/abs/2009.04980, https://mathscinet.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=4224071

shows that infinitesimals in NSA can be handled conservatively over ZF (without the axiom of choice).  Meanwhile, to construct the isomorphism between maximal class-size surreals and hyperreals as in Theorem 20 in Ehrlich

Ehrlich, Philip.
The absolute arithmetic continuum and the unification of all numbers great and small. Bull. Symbolic Logic18(2012), no.1, 1–45

one needs not merely the axiom of choice but the axiom of global choice, a stronger axiom in the context of NBG (von Neumann-Bernays-Gödel set theory with global choice).
